# JavaScript: Can we convert 7-segment numbers made of characters(_ & |) into parsed number using javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

JavaScript: Can we convert 7-segment numbers made of characters(_ & |) into parsed number using javascript/angularjs

Input :

```
 
      _  _     _  _  _  _  _  
    | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_| 
    ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _|
```

Output :

```
123456789
```

Comment: the anwer is yes, but what have you tried?

Comment: Well I am new to angularJS so I am not getting how to do this.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with one particular framework, it's about programming in general, and how to solve a problem. JS and angular only describe the context/tools you have. So, how would you approach the problem in general?

Comment: Using my past experiences, I would analyse the problem, think for an alternative, try to debug using coding

Comment: you have at least two possibilites to solve the problem, one by checking the pattern as string, and the other to identify the segments and use a binary operation for checking the number.

Comment: @NinaScholz : Do you have any working example to support this?

Comment: @user7549774, Did you actually try anything on your own? We're not a free code service.

Comment: Your last answer is just a bunch of empty phrases. `Using my past experiences` great, that's how we learn and grow, `I would analyse the problem` go on, please analyse it. `think for an alternative` an alternative to the problem? either you have a problem, or you don't. `try to debug` that's actually the point you should have asked this question. When you're right at some particular problem and fail at debugging it on your own. `using coding` yes pleeeeeease, show us some/your code. Then we have something to talk about. Nina told you two possible ways how **you** could approach the problem.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for your expert opinion Thomas, but if you cant help then please keep your thoughts upto you only, it might hurt others. As you rightly said that you dont provide free service so I would suggest you to keep yourself out of this, it will save both of our times in a big way.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the encoding of a [seven-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display) and the following

- split by linefeed `'\n'`
- build an array with single ASCII digits
- join a single ASCII digit to a string
- map the ASCII value
- join the result to a string

The ASCII value is taken with an object for a number, and the single segments are weighted with a value for the segment.

Value of segments is 2<sup>n</sup>.

> ```
>   _0_    
> |5   1|
>   _6_  
> |4   2|
>   _3_
> ```

Dots as segments

> ```
>  0
> 561
> 432
> ```

This generates the string

> ```
> '909561432'
>   ^ ^^^^^^  denoted segments with the number above
>  ^ ^        no segments
> ```

---

> For example, take
>
> ```
>  012
> 0
> 1  |
> 2  |
> ```
>
> the ASCII string of 1, and the above segment numbers, then you get for the segment `1` the value 2<sup>1</sup> and for `2` the value 2<sup>2</sup>. The result is `2 + 4 = 6`.
>
> After a lookup in the bits object,
>
> ```
> {
>     63: 0,
>     6: 1, // <----
>     91: 2, 
>     /* ... */
> }
> ```
>
> you get the digit `1`.

```js
function get7segment(ascii) {
    return ascii.
        split('\n').
        reduce(function (r, a, i) {
            a.match(/.../g).forEach(function (b, j) {
                r[j] = r[j] || [];
                r[j][i] = b;
            });
            return r;
        }, []).
        map(function (a) {
            return a.join('');
        }).
        map(function (a) {
            var bits = { 63: 0, 6: 1, 91: 2, 79: 3, 102: 4, 109: 5, 125: 6, 7: 7, 127: 8, 111: 9, 0: ' ' },
                v = '909561432'.split('').reduce(function (r, v, i) {
                    return r + ((a[i] !== ' ') << v);
                }, 0);
            return v in bits ? bits[v] : '*'; // * is an illegal character
        }).
        join('');
}

function print(ascii) {
    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.innerHTML = ascii + '\n\n' + get7segment(ascii);
    document.body.appendChild(pre);
}

print(' _     _  _     _  _  _  _  _ \n| |  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_| \n|_|  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _|');
print('    _  _  _    ...\n  | _| _|  |   ...\n  | _| _|  |   ...');
print('    _  _  _  _  _ \n|_||_|| ||_||_   |\n  | _||_||_||_|  |');
```

Comment: thats great, how did you do that?

Comment: Can you please explain how did you binded 7 segment pattern to var data1, data2 ? Cant we have same variable for binding both. Considering a scenarion we have two numbers returned to same string.

Comment: what do you mean by *binding both*?

Comment: Got it ! but will this same function works for variable holding both numbers 123456789 and 1331 together with former placed above and latter beneath(in & segment characters).Also can we check for illegal tokens like '?'  or ',' ?

Comment: there is no check for illegal characters, bur you could ch in advance for illegal characters. you might get some undefined value for missing keys in the object.

Comment: <pre>
      _  _      _  _  _  _  _ 
    | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|
    ||_  _|   | _||_|  ||_| _| 
                              
       _  _  _  _    
  |_||_||  ||_||  |  
    |  _||_||_||_|  
                              
</pre>

Comment: please add the string to your question.

Comment: Download image for your reference: [link](http://imgur.com/vKIQAgg)

Comment: @user7549774, what should i do with the image?

Comment: This is in refer to my question as one of a scenario where I can have numbers split as shown in image. Write now you are using two variables for both numbers, how come if these numbers are clubbed just like screenshot

Comment: then you need an algorithm to separate the two numbers.

Comment: Hi @Nina  Can you please tell me one thinkgs, In this line   {    v = '909561432'.split('').reduce(function (r, v, i)    } why you have taken 909561432 this number and what is the use ?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, it's the single value of the segment, please see above, in the section: Value of segments is 2^n. the value of `9` ist just denote the these segments are not valid.

Comment: Thanks@Nina  , I know how you create
 {
    63: 0,
    6: 1, 
    91: 2,
} 

But didn't get 909561432 this number , Can you be more specific please. How you are calculating this 909561432 ?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, maybe the edit helps a bit.